# HTML select input losing its value when switching between views with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, forms

I have a single controller with multiple views which are navigated with ui-router.

One of these views has a `select` input. The options for this `select` are loaded from array with simple objects. My model value is integer, so I want to bind to a property inside the object (as we know, Angular treats `option` values as strings and does strict comparison, so I need a directive to convert to/from integer, and this part seems to work fine in my code). It works fine, as long as I stay on the view with `select`. But the problems start when I switch between views. Although the model preserves its value, the `select` gets reset and shows wrong value.

How to make `select` survive ui-router's navigation?

Here is a Plunker to show the issue:
http://embed.plnkr.co/dVQTtHpu7GYqOyN2yyVH/preview

Comment: @JustMartin Every time controller get initialized when you navigate to page back. Which mean you should keep selected option value in service.

Comment: @Mohan Singh: My case is a bit non-standard - I don't specify controller for the state. My ng-controller is outside - the same controller instance for both views - and even its constructor is called only once and not while navigating. If controller would get reinitialized, then the model value also would be lost, but it is not - it stays and is displayed correctly when I switch between views. Only `select` value is being displayed wrong.

Comment: Why do not you ng-options ?

Comment: @Mohan Singh Because as much as I tried, it was loading entire selected object into my model, and not just the `id` property. But it seems, I was not clever enough - see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<select ng-model="cntrlr.model.lang_id" ng-options="idx*1 as var.name for (idx, var) in cntrlr.languages">
        </select>
```

http://embed.plnkr.co/lBmsDLUXJjfIf2Tc08UI/preview

Comment: Thanks, this works. What a smart use of `ng-options`, I would never think of such a trick.

Comment: Actually I found it myself in some question in stack-overflow one day but could not find the original answer it was from. Sorry so credits is not 100% from me

Comment: There is just one drawback I found - it works fine as long as "id" fields are in the same sequence as `idx`, but if they are not, then still I cannot bind directly to model.lang_id but have to use some intermediate model value which then selects the right record by index from `languages`.